# Start job from python, redirect output to file

Tags: python, redirect

I have a script, `update_file`, that I typically run like so:

`sudo update_file (file) > ./logs/(file) &`

I was wondering what the proper syntax/is it possible, to call this script from within a Python script and still have it redirect output from `update_file` to a file and have it created as a system job.

EDIT: I should note, I run this against multiple `(file)`s so I would like to pass that as a variable.

Comment: "have it created as a system job", do you mean to have it keep running after the Python script has ended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `subprocess` module is how you execute programs from Python. The section [Replacing Older Functions with the `subprocess` Module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module) in the documentation shows you how to transform typical shell functionality into Python.

Because you're using `&` to background the task, you'll want to create a `Popen`, and do the job-handling later. So:

```
jobs = []

# ... each time you want to run it on a file ...

jobs.append(subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'update_file', file],
                             stdout=open(os.path.join('logs', file), 'w'))

# ... at exit time ...

for job in jobs:
    job.wait()
    job.stdout.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("sudo update_file(file)",stdout=open("logs/(file)","w"))
```

maybe?

Comment: Could [popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) be what they are looking for?

Comment: He wants `(file)` to be a variable. Also, the `&` implies that he doesn't want to wait for it to finish, so `call` isn't the right thing here. And you've removed one of the spaces between parameters. And you really really want to use a list of params rather than a string on POSIX platforms; otherwise, you have to handle, e.g., escaping the `file` variable yourself.

Comment: yeah he edited it after i answered to make that more clear I guess ... anyway your answer is the right one :)